# docxtpl как загрузить переменую

Tags: python, переменные, ms-word, модули, docxtpl

В модуле docxtpl есть функция context принимающая переменную в word текстовое значение на которое надо заменить переменную.
Пример:

```
context={'a3':"привет"}
```

Но он не может принимать переменную python.
Пример(не работает):

```
context={'a3':v1}
```

Как можно заставить принимать эту функцию и переменные тоже.

Мой код:

```
from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
doc = DocxTemplate("test.docx")
v1="ad"
b1="vfb"
context={"a3":v1}
print(v1)
context={"a4":b1}
print(b1)
doc.render(context)
doc.save("tests.docx")
```

[image: исходный файл]
[image: итоговый файл]

Comment: Это работает. Приведите полный воспроизводимый пример и скриншот шаблона документа.

Comment: from docxtpl import DocxTemplate
doc = DocxTemplate("test.docx")
v1="ad"
b1="vfb"
context={"a3":v1}
print(v1)
context={"a4":b1}
print(b1)
doc.render(context)
doc.save("tests.docx")

Comment: Код и шаблон добавьте в сам вопрос, не в комментарии.

Comment: спасибо помогло

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его принятым, поставив галку слева от ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы вторым присваиванием `context={"a4":b1}` перезаписываете старое значение `context={"a3":v1}` полностью, из-за этого при вызове `doc.render(context)` подставляется только вторая переменная.

Нужно создавать context за один раз:

```
context={"a3":v1, "a4":b1}
```

Ну либо добавлять значения как в обычный словарь, не перезатирая переменную context полностью:

```
context = dict()
context["a3"] = v1
context["a4"] = b1
```